# Convert binary file data to normal .txt

Tags: java, file, hex, ascii

I recently formatted my hard drive and forgot to save a java project from it. After trying to recover those files with recovery tools found on internet, I got the files back but... the content is unreadable; i.e. my Main.java class looks like :

```
108b 4424 5085 ff8b 403c 7e10 8b7c 2410
8904 2489 7c24 04e8 74b0 0200 8b74 2428
8d45 07c7 4424 2000 0000 0089 4424 1885
f60f 8e52 0100 0090 8b44 2450 8b7c 2420
8b4c 2410 8b40 1885 c98b 04b8 8944 2424
8b44 2450 8b40 248b 3cb8 8b44 2450 8b40
3c89 4424 1c0f 8e3d 0100 0031 f631 ed89
7c24 2c89 f7eb 0e90 c604 2f00 83c5 013b
6c24 1074 3f39 f57c ef8b 4424 1c8d 7436
0189 7424 0489 0424 e8f3 af02 0089 6c24
0889 7c24 0489 0424 8944 2414 e86f a202
...
```

What is this exactly? Is there a way I can write like a python script to translate it back to a readable java class ? Simple hexadecimal to ascii doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure that is the source code file?

Comment: This looks more like executable assembly - binary opcodes for an Intel processor.

Comment: Well when I open the recovered Main.java with a text editor (Sublime Text), this is the data I get. I don't really know what it actually represents and how I can get it back correctly ?

Comment: this is not a plain text file anyway

Comment: @Waroulolz - Sublime Text I believe automatically gives you a hex view of binary files. That's not the actual, textual content of the file. Whatever hex-to-ascii gives you should be correct, meaning you've recovered garbage.

Comment: I don't know much really about what I am trying to achieve. Can you tell me if I can convert this binary file to what I am looking for ?

Comment: No, because the binary file simply is not what you're looking for. What you're looking for likely is not there. (You mention it should be Java source, but Java source can't start with the ASCII code for "backspace", nor should it have null bytes in it.)

Comment: You could maaaybe try renaming the file to some other extension to see if it's any common binary file format, like a ZIP archive or a PDF document or an image, if it's at all likely you had a misnamed file or that the recovery tool got the name wrong somehow. But I'm mostly guessing your data is toast.

Comment: This is executable (compiled) code – or at least a fragment, as it does not start with a valid header. From the second byte on, it contains valid 80X86 instructions: `mov     eax, [esp+50h]` `test    edi, edi` `mov     eax, [eax+3Ch]` `jle     short loc_1011C` `mov     edi, [esp+10h]` (and so on). It's worthless, for your purposes.

Comment: @Jongware Good catch. I initially thought it might be a badly named Java `.class` file, but the start doesn't have the right magic number, so even if it was it'd be a useless fragment. (And even then, there are basically none of the opcodes I'd expect to be really common.) I'm guessing the recovery software found an orphaned filesystem record for a file called `Main.java` that got deleted and overwritten with a .exe file?